# Python - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting, typeerror

I have written the following code, for some reason its giving an error when the code is applied, not sure what the issue is.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
eventRootOids = ('1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.%s')

EVENT_TRAP_VARBINDS = {
                'ApplicationId'      : tuple(['ApplicationId'] + [oid % 1 for oid in eventRootOids]),
                 Console'        : tuple(['Console'] + [oid% 2 for oid in eventRootOids]),
                       }
```

My ROOT OID is supposed to be `1.3.61.4.1.44.2.17.19.2.2.1/2/3` so on..)

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
                'ApplicationId'      : tuple(['ApplicationId'] + [oid % 1 for oid in eventRootOids]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were missing a comma in `eventRootOids = ('1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.%s')`; the way you wrote it it was not a tuple.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

eventRootOids = ('1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.%s', )

EVENT_TRAP_VARBINDS = { 'ApplicationId' : 
    tuple(['ApplicationId'] + [oid % 1 for oid in eventRootOids]), 
    'Console' : tuple(['Console'] + [oid % 2 for oid in eventRootOids]), }

print(EVENT_TRAP_VARBINDS)
```

output:

```
{'ApplicationId': 
    ('ApplicationId', '1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.1'),
    'Console': ('Console', '1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.17.19.2.2.2')
}
```